# iReport generates different PDFs than Web App

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports, ireport

I have some troubles with JasperReports. I generated a formular with iReport including two subreports which generates a grid of values (1 or 2 Characters long).

The compiled PDF from iReport it works fine and looks good, but if i use the same *.jrxml and *.jasper files for my web app the generated PDF has some minor differences. One big problem is, that some cells of the grid now are 2 lines high. Values like "NB" only use one line but "GS" for example uses 2 lines.

For me it is not possible to find the error. Workarounds with smaller font size or wider cells didn't help.

Comment: `2 lines long` = `2 lines height`?

Comment: @Ischin yes, the characters are one below the other

Comment: Could you post a screenshots of the `compiled PDF from iReport` and `generated PDF from webapp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the font you are using in the template is available on the JVM generating the report.  If the font doesn't exist then a different font will be used.  If changing the font isn't an option then you can create a font extension package.  Creating a font extension is documented here: [JasperReports Font Reference](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/sample.reference/fonts/index.html)

Comment: thanks, it was a problem with the font. There are no problems if I use the Deja Vu default font.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you could have a different version of iReports in your web application.  Making the cells sufficiently wide enough should at least allow the text to span just one line.

Create a Java Desktop test that generates a PDF based on the .jrxml and make sure it has the same results.  If it does then there is something with the way iReports is working, if it doesn't then you know it is something with how you are viewing or creating the PDF in the web app.